# How to use variable in scrapy xpath array

Tags: python, scrapy

```
xpath('//*[@id="tb"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/text()')
xpath('//*[@id="tb"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/text()')
xpath('//*[@id="tb"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/text()')
xpath('//*[@id="tb"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/text()')
xpath('//*[@id="tb"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/text()')
xpath('//*[@id="tb"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/text()')
xpath('//*[@id="tb"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[7]/text()')
```

I want to replace tr[3] with a variable

ex>  tr[3] -> tr[A]

I tried this ...

```
xpath('//*[@id="tb"]/table/tbody/tr[' a ']/td[7]/text()')   -not work
xpath('//*[@id="tb"]/table/tbody/tr[' " a " ']/td[7]/text()') -not work
xpath('//*[@id="tb"]/table/tbody/tr[" ' a ' "]/td[7]/text()') -not work
xpath('//*[@id="tb"]/table/tbody/tr['+ a +']/td[7]/text()') -not work
xpath('//*[@id="tb"]/table/tbody/tr[' "+ a +" ']/td[7]/text()')  -not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [**string formatting `str.format(..)`**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
xpath('//*[@id="tb"]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[7]/text()'.format(a))
#                                   ^ placeholder     ^ format call
```

This will replace the `{}` pattern by the string representation of `a`.